# CS50 Mario - Less Comfortable - Last Step

Tags: c, cs50

I have essentially rounded out the Mario.c assignment for CS50, I am having trouble with the last part of the problem, which is to add an incrementing number of dots'.' before each hash set. I cannot seem to get rid of the last dot, and cannot figure out a solution within my do-while loop that will fix it.

My code so far:

```
int main(void)
{
    int i;
    do
    {
        i = get_int ("Height: ");
    }
    while (i < 1 || i > 8);

    for (int b = 0; b < i; b++)
    {
        int d = i - 1;
        do
        {
            printf(".");
            d--;
        }
        while (d > b);
        
        for (int c = 0; c < b + 1; c++)
        {
            printf("#");
        }

        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

This returns in the console like this:

```
.......#
......##
.....###
....####
...#####
..######
.#######
.########
```

I am simply trying to get rid of the very last dot on the eighth row.

I have tried everything but it remains nonetheless.

Any thoughts/hints?

Comment: Welcome! Consider using a `while()` loop for `printf(".");` instead of a `do ... while()` loop, which will run at least once. But I would think that many coders will use a `for` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you use a `do...while` loop in for the condition of putting the `.`'s in place.  Don't use a do while loop there. Use a traditional while loop.

You use a `do...while` loop when you want to unconditionally perform the loop at least once.  You use a while loop when you need to check a condition first.

In this case however I think you should be using a for loop instead of a while loop but thats a seperate issue.

Generally you use a while loop when you have no notion in general of how many times it needs to be evaluated and its not straight forward that somethign has to be incremented every single time.

When you know the bounds of the times the loop needs to operate and your counter has to increase every single time you perform the loop you generally want a `for` loop.

In this case: `for (int d = i - 1; d < b; d++) { .... }`

Answer (score 1):

You do not need this complicated while loops

```
    for (int b = 0; b < i; b++)
    {
        for(int a = 0 ; a < i; a++)
            printf("%c", a >= b ? '.' : '#');
        printf("\n");
    }
```

you can also use `if` instead:

```
    for (int b = 0; b < i; b++)
    {
        for(int a = 0 ; a < i; a++)
            if(a >= b) printf(".");
              else printf("#");
        printf("\n");
    }
```

is enough. Just changing the comparison you can change the shape.

Example:

```
int main(void)
{
    int i;
    do
    {
        i = get_int ("Height: ");
    }
    while (i < 1 || i > 8);

    printf("\n");
    for (int b = 0; b < i; b++)
    {
        for(int a = 0 ; a < i; a++)
            printf("%c", a >= b ? '.' : '#');
        printf("\n");
    }

    printf("\n");
    for (int b = 0; b < i; b++)
    {
        for(int a = 0 ; a < i; a++)
            printf("%c", a <= b ? '.' : '#');
        printf("\n");
    }

    printf("\n");
    for (int b = 0; b < i; b++)
    {
        for(int a = 0 ; a < i; a++)
            printf("%c", i - a > b ? '.' : '#');
        printf("\n");
    }

    printf("\n");
    for (int b = 0; b < i; b++)
    {
        for(int a = 0 ; a < 8; a++)
            printf("%c", i - a <= b ? '.' : '#');
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

And the result:

```
........
#.......
##......
###.....
####....
#####...
######..
#######.

.#######
..######
...#####
....####
.....###
......##
.......#
........

........
.......#
......##
.....###
....####
...#####
..######
.#######

########
#######.
######..
#####...
####....
###.....
##......
#.......
```

Comment: That's a really elegant way to go about it that's quite compact. I hadn't thought of that.  That aside you gave them the answer to the code when they are trying to learn the very basics. They haven't covered tertiary expressions yet in their lessons at this point. This is their first or second thing after hello world pretty much

Comment: @UpAndAdam replace it with `if` then.

Comment: sure.. like I said I love your solution and I upvoted it.